# How to make a deepcopy of asyncio.Queue?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm trying to make a `deepcopy` of `asyncio.Queue` in my `aiohttp` server but I'm getting `TypeError: can't pickle _asyncio.Future objects`.

Is there any way I can perform a walk through the async-queue without having to put the items back to the queue? What I really want to achieve is to work with some kind of a snapshot of the queue eg. memoryview of the queue.

My whole idea is to do:

```
import asyncio
import copy

q = asyncio.Queue()
await q.put(1)
await q.put(2)

qc = copy.deepcopy(q). # I don't really care about Futures during this copy
done = list()

while not qc.empty()
  done.append(await qc.get())

max(done)  # or similar algorithm I cannot do with asyncio.Queue
```

I also wonder how the `asyncio.Queue` `__repr__` is implemented, since it prints the whole list of items in the queue without the extra effort for getting/putting them back.

## Full traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "copyasyncq.py", line 32, in foo
    queue_copy = copy.deepcopy(aq)

       ...

TypeError: can't pickle _asyncio.Future objects
Exception ignored in: <function BaseEventLoop.__del__ at 0x105d75840>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 621, in __del__
    if not self.is_closed():
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 618, in is_closed
    return self._closed
AttributeError: '_UnixSelectorEventLoop' object has no attribute '_closed'
```